# Howto Enable Font Antialiasing in Windows

Tags: fonts, windows-xp, antialiasing

I have downloaded a font that looks less than desirable if it is not anti-aliased.  I can not figure out how to enable anti-aliasing in VS, I have changed the 'Smooth Edges of Screen Fonts' in the system performance options but that does not seem to help.

VS2008 on XP SP3.

What am I missing?

Comment: Move to [superuser](http://superuser.com/)?

Comment: way too old to be migrated

Comment: You say that @ThiefMaster as if one should have any bearing on the other.

Comment: It's simply not possible to migrate questions older than six months.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try using ClearType, not Standard font smoothing.

It's in Display properties, Appearance, Effects.

Comment: It is the [Liberation Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_fonts) font. @Blorgbeard That is **exactly** what I was looking for. I was thinking that the setting in computer performance was the only one. It looks like a charm now.

Comment: I had ugly fonts in my IDE on work computer and thought it was an unsolvable problem, it made me angry... thank you so much for this solution!

Comment: Brought here by an ugly IDE editor too :D

Answer (score 5):

In Windows 7:

> **Control Panel** | **Display** | **Adjust ClearType text**

This starts a 4-step calibration process.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a problem with the color combination? Some fonts look really ugly on high contrast combinations with a black background.

Also, can you see the difference in the fonts in any other application?

Which font is it?