# Something like glow next to div

Tags: html, css

Can someone tell me why is there something like white glow/shadow next to my div (on the right side)? At first, I thought that border is smaller than div, but it's not that. This only happens when I use dark color as background.
Maybe you won't see, but take a close look on image below.

[image]:

Here is a close up of the line:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
#container {
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 5px solid #000000;
    background-color: #990000;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to look on Chrome inspector what it is?

Comment: Without the code, there's really no way to tell...

Comment: I can't see anything white, and neither can my color picker. Are you sure you're not the victim of some weird optical illusion here?

Comment: Code added and yeah, I tried to use inspector but it shows even in Adobe Photoshop..
I'm not victim of some wierd optical illusion, even my brother and sister see the white line. :)
EDIT:
There is something strange, I see the line and when I take a picture with my phone I see it, everyone in my house see it, but color picker don't. Hmmm.

Comment: This is only a little part of the code and doesn't really help. But I can't see a white line on retina macbook, too ...

Comment: Opening the image in Photoshop CS6, I see a clear cut between `#ddd` and  `#920011` in the image you provided, with no colors inbetween...

Comment: maybe if you upload the file we could all have a look and inspect it, but from here I don't see a thing

Comment: Here is the full code on pastebin - http://pastebin.com/5rQtMyTa

Comment: I think I see the line, and I edited the post to show a close up, but I don't think it is a big deal since it is so hard to notice.

Comment: I know it's not a big deal, but I want to know what is that. For those who don't see the white line, use your phone's camera on image I included with my post.

Comment: The image you included in the post is being scaled down to fit the width of SO. In certain browsers (such as Firefox for me, and probably the browser you're using), the image is being anti-aliased in order to provide a more intentional look than nearest neighbour scaling would. This usually doesn't go well with hard color clashes such as in pixel art, or your example image. But whatever the original result of your code would be can't possibly have that problem, as only images are treated this way, not styled containers.

Comment: Yeah, it's contrast between light and dark color, when I changed background to darker color white line dissapeared. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simply the anti-alias effect, caused by the image tool, or monitor, you use.

When have high contrast color next to each other, this often happens.

Turn of anti-alias when doing the screen dump/paste into the image tool and it will be gone

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you put in and when I run it on here I definitely don't see a white line. Click run snippet and then full page. Then zoom in as much as possible. I think it is gone meaning that the line is probably caused by your browser or something else other than the code.

I might try using a css normalizer. Good Luck!

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Myriad Pro;
    src: url('fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf');
}
 
body {
    background-color: #DEDEDE;
    font-family: Myriad Pro;
}
 
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1738E0;
}
 
textarea:focus, input:focus, button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
 
#container {
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 5px solid #000000;
    background-color: #990000;
    width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="yay">
    Ugly thing...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see the line when I run that code. Strange... Maybe my monitor have problems...

Comment: Have you tried using a css normalizer to make sure there is no weird padding, margins, or anything like that? It also quite possibly could be, like @LGSon said, an anti-alias effect. I looked it up and I think that it can be caused by moniters as well. You could try looking it up to see if you can turn anti-aliasing off on you moniter.

Comment: @dovlapsy What kind of monitor do you use? ... If it is a CRT, then that is exactly what happens when 1 dark and 1 light color meets, you get that "glow", a kind of anti-alias or else it would be kind of a jagged edge.

Comment: @dovlapsy Ok, is your browser zoomed?

Comment: I think that it is probably in your monitor because I don't see the line in the example I provided. Is there an anti-aliasing setting on your monitor?

Comment: My browser is not zoomed and yeah, I also saw the same glow line when I was learning Regex on their site. http://regexone.com/
@Taylor I have no idea is there any settings about anti aliasing..

Comment: If you are using Windows, it is in display properties -> appearance -> effects according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44721/howto-enable-font-antialiasing-in-windows